# Correct reference but wrong hyperlinks with tcolorbox and thmtools

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, tcolorbox, debugging, thmtools

After spending several hours tracking down an issue with wrong hyperlinks in my thesis, I managed to cook up the following MWE:

```
%!TEX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{hyperref,cleveref}
\usepackage{thmtools} % <-- comment this out to fix the issue!
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{xparse}

\DeclareTColorBox[auto counter,number within=section,crefname={example}{examples}]{example}{ g O{} }{%
    IfValueTF={#1}{title={example~\thetcbcounter\ (#1)}}{title=example~\thetcbcounter},#2
    }

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
\begin{example}[label=ex:test]{My title}
    Foo.
\end{example}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\begin{example}[label=ex:test2]{My title}
    Foo.
\end{example}

This was \cref{ex:test2}.
The number is right, but the hyperlink leads to \cref{ex:test}.

\end{document}
```

If `thmtools` is loaded the hyperlink to the second example is wrong, otherwise everything works as expected. This behavior seems unwanted to me, i.e. the declarations using `tcolorbox` should not interfere with `thmtools`. Additionally the fact, that the reference is right but the hyperlink wrong is very odd.

As I am not really dependent on `thmtools` I have no hard time disabling it, but I am interested in the reason for this behavior and wanted to report this as a possible bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply try to load `hyperref` as late as possible (rule of thumb), so the order

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
```

will not show your problem.

A possible cause could be that `thmtools.sty` loads `thm-autoref.sty` which does some hyperlink modifications cleveref or hyperref may conflict with.

Comment: Yes, `thmtools` modifies the labels